# How to deploy war on remote Tomcat

Tags: maven, tomcat, maven-plugin

I would like to deploy a WAR on remotely located Tomcat using maven-tomcat plugin. But having problems with it and getting exception (mentioned below). Please guide.

## Command Used:

```
mvn tomcat:redeploy
```

## Error Log:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project PageNameService: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection refused: connect - [Help 1]
```

## settings.xml

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>UnixTomcatServer</id>
            <username>manager</username>
            <password>manager</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

## tomcat-users.xml

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="manager" password="manager" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,admin" />
```

## pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.study.apigee</groupId>
    <artifactId>PageNameService</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>PageNameService</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://secdevapp11.gspt.net:8888/manager</url>
                    <server>UnixTomcatServer</server>
                    <path>/{project.artifactId}</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Have you deployed the Tomcat `manager` web application into your server?

Comment: Yes and I can access it using http://secdevapp11.gspt.net:8888/manager

Comment: Good. Sorry, Tomcat-Maven isn't my strong-suit. If you don't get any replies here, try posting to the tomcat-user mailing list.

Comment: I inspected the logs again and it says "Deploying war to http://localhost:8080/PageNameService" which is wrong since I am trying to deploy to "http://secdevap11.gspt.net:8888"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to update your manager url with `text` its new change as of tomcat7 from tomcat6

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://secdevapp11.gspt.net:8888/manager/text</url>
        <server>UnixTomcatServer</server>
        <path>/{project.artifactId}</path>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now you can run mvn tomcat7:deploy( or redeploy)