# How to make a web app for remote tomcat server on local machine

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat

I have installed a `Tomcat 9` on an `Ubuntu server 18.04` running on a `VM` and now I want to deploy an example app wrote by me so I can at least get the hang of it.

**Now the problem** is all of the tutorials I've found on how to write a web app for tomcat and then deploy it(I wanted to make the web app on my local machine and then deploy it as a WAR file to the server running on my VM) tell me that I need a runtime target which needs to be the server.

Seeing how my server is running on a VM I do not know how or if it is possible to use a remote target.

**Now my question is:** Is there any way to write a web app in Java for a Tomcat server(I've installed Eclipse for this, but I can use any other IDE) without having the server installed on my local machine?

Comment: You need some tools like maven or gradle. Those tools have plugins wich permit you to deploy remotely your package (in your case .war). It will take you a while so be patient!

Comment: If I understood your question, this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22333885/how-to-deploy-war-on-remote-tomcat

Comment: So you are saying that with these tools I can make my example web app on my machine and then deploy it to the remote server ? Sorry if I am not giving too much technical information, I am a complete noob in web dev. @MontassarElBéhi

Comment: My problem is that I want to make a web app project in Eclipse or some other IDE, export it as WAR file and then deploy it to the server, but as I have noticed you need to have a server running on your local machine. Is this really necessary or can I do it without the local server ? @NickAth

Comment: You do not need to have any local server into your local machine since you want to deploy your .war file into a remote server.

Comment: If you believe your code will be perfect and working from the beginning, then you don't need local server. Because local server is used for testing your work before you deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is a server which is used to run you web application so if you are writing the code you dont need a server up and running on your local machine. Tomcat server or any server is needed if you want to deploy your application may be for your testing before you deploy